# AngularJS popover bind to controller variable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to create a popover and load content into it directly from a controller.

I can succesfully bind `flag` into the tooltip using a directive from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25656707/4277702), but the popover keeps showing the initial value of `flag`, even if I change `flag`'s value with the second button.

> The point is that I wish the content of the popover to change
>   dinamically along with the variable in the controller.
>
> How can I make the trick?

Here's the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('popover', function($compile, $timeout){
return {
restrict: 'A',
link:function(scope, el, attrs){
  var content = attrs.content;
  var settings = scope.$eval(attrs.popover);
  var elm = angular.element('<div />');
  elm.append(attrs.content);
  $compile(elm)(scope);
  $timeout(function() {
    el.removeAttr('popover').attr('data-content',elm.html());
    el.popover(settings);
   });
  }
}
```

Here comes the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Umz8NH)

**2ND STEP**

I wish I can set the container of the popover to be the `<body>` using that directive, so I can make the popover width 1/3 of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem here is that the `popover-template` directive using a template which route is stored as a string in a `$scope` variable (as suggested by @kpentchev in the comments of the other answer) is available only with the `angular-bootstrap` [version 0.13.0](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3553#issuecomment-93795890).

That version is [not available in npm](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3632) yet, so after I manually updated it using bower I was able to use correctly my custom popover.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first problem with updating the body value - you are not binding to the scope variable, but are reading the value assigned to the element attribute in `var content = attrs.content;`

Since you are already using bootstrap popover, take a look at [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), who have implemented a popover directive. They support custom templates using the `popover-template` attribute.

Comment: The angular-ui bootstrap popover is ok, but I still can't pass it a template successfully; I placed a template named "popoverInfo.html" in the view folder (I used Yeoman to scaffold the web-app, so I refer to a so built directory tree) but it won't load neither by passing `popover-template="popoverInfo.html"` to the element nor `popover-template="views/popoverInfo.html"`.Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Gargaroz can you use firebug or simiral to check that the XSR request made by angular is made against the URI where your template is hosted?

Comment: Pointed that when I modify the `popoverInfo.html` the webapp reloads correctly due to Grunt, I took a look to the network tab in the Chrome dev console and no `popoverInfo.html` is being fetched.

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4n3sp11k5eKdS264hM56) complete, still can't show the tooltip template.

Comment: can you at least provide some hints on what I'm missing in the scenario from my plunker?

Comment: @Gargaroz , For once, no `ng-app` defined and secondly, `popover-template` requires a reference to a scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the final html of the popover is not the one you compiled, just a copy of it.

You can instead set the `content` option to the compiled element itself:

```
    // remove the attribute so the popover will look at the content option value
    el.removeAttr('data-content');
    settings.content = elm;
    el.popover(settings);
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3q3cjhem8IK13hVj9JK4?p=preview).